# QuickCheck catch-22

Tags: testing, haskell

I'm working on a Haskell project and I started out by organizing it like this:

- `blah.hs` holds the majority of the code
- `blah_main.hs` has the main program
- and `blah_test.hs` has the test cases.

The problem with this is that restricting the functions exported by `blah.hs` means restricting the functions that can be tested from `blah_test.hs`.  Is there a good way around this issue?  Because I'd really like to write test code for some of the "internal" functions that aren't being exported by `blah.hs`.

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: Nice answer both from Mikhail and Michael.  Turns out that Michael's answer is better for me in this case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Move internal functions from the `Blah.*` modules to `Blah.Internal.*` . You can hide internal modules from the users of your library by listing them in the `other-modules` field in the `blah.cabal` file (instead of `exposed-modules`, where you list all modules visible to the users). Look at [Hakyll](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll)'s [.cabal file](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hakyll/3.1.2.7/hakyll.cabal) for an example.

Comment: I agree about moving functions to `Blah.Internal.*`, but please don't hide the module.  Users need access to module internals more frequently than you would expect, such as for making data types instances of new classes, or implementing optimized/strict/nonstrict variants, or a number of other good reasons.  Name the module as Internal but leave it exposed, and users will know not to bother with it unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Mikhail over all, but in some circumstances it's not really possible to make such a split. In those cases, I would recommend using the CPP (C Pre-Processor) extension, along the lines of:

```
module Blah
    ( public
#if TEST
    , private
#endif
    ) where
```